# How to integrate github with siebel instead of SVN for checking in and checkingout the objects?

Tags: github, crm, siebel

Please help me the solution.I couldn't find resources online.Any help will be helpful.

Comment: Try asking Oracle support

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's any official support or best practices for this. If your team wanted to do it, I'd suggest creating an agreed upon directory structure containing and scripts, web templates, sifs, etc. that you want in your source control. You may want to look into [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) if you decide to store your SRF files in the repo.

From my own experience, I've been happy just keeping several local git repos on my work PC that contain different bits of functionality, scripts, and their sifs.

Edit: Note, this can get a bit cumbersome when objects are used by multiple things, meaning you may have the same code/sifs in multiple small Git repos. Perhaps a single, large repo would work better, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your own windows executable .exe or some other script which can take inputs from Siebel's check in process. Tools will pass 4 parameters to the bat file during checkin as per [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/UsingTools/checking_in_and_out22.html) documentation. For reference, check out how some others have got it working with SVN [here](https://knowingsiebel.wordpress.com/2015/09/30/integrating-siebel-with-svn-subversion/) and [here](http://www.michaelwilliams.co.za/using-subversion-with-siebel/).

My siebel project uses git, but I cannot share the source of the script due to NDAs. The script is similiar that it simply parses and passes the inputs to git.exe on windows.